# SignalR - how to secure client to make sure that the user doesn't create his own client

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, signalr

im curently working on some application backend based on rest api/signalr (C#/.Net Core). Both protocol are open - how can i secure backend to work only with authorized application and block the possibility of creating unauthorized client?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on how seriously you want to lock down access to your backend. But generally, solving the trust issue is never cheap.

- Investigate things like SSL Pinning and Certificate Transparency, which are a good start but not infallible
- Next look into an API Management Gateway (APIM) which can be put in front of API's to manage access. This normally works by giving clients an access token. But this token can be compromised. A better approach is to have access to the API via a Gateway controlled through user specific access tokens. But this isn't always practical.
- If that doesn't meet your access control requirements you then need to add a Web Application Firewall (sometimes called a WAF) which can monitor, filter and block undesirable traffic

Whatever approach you take, normally how much you want to lock it down scales with how much money you'll need to invest.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot. You must always assume that the client is hostile, but this is *especially* true of technologies based on HTTP. Whatever proofs you try to put in the client can *usually* be extracted by a suitably motivated malicious party and used in their hacked hostile client. Or more likely: they can just use their browser tools or tools like Fiddler to see, manipulate, and replay commands.

All logic must be at the server. If the client wants to duplicate the logic for a better user-experience, fine: but you cannot trust any ruling made by a client - the server must recheck.